# Reclaim storage from Azure database for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, azure, storage, backup

We have an Azure database for Postgres Flexible Server option. Server has been allocated to 512GB, and total size of all databases on the server is about 110G. We had online backups set up for the maximum allowed retention period of 35 days. This had started on July 17th, 2023. Since then, space used on the server has been growing at a fairly steady rate and monitoring showed it approaching 95% used. Instead of upscaling the Azure server to the next size (1TB), we reduced the online backup retention to 8 days (we are also doing offline daily backups, so point in time recovery will still be possible for 8 days, but a catastrophic failure/research recovery would still be available for much longer periods of time).

However, space used on the server continues to creep up. Granted, 35 days has not yet passed and old backups have not begin to fall off the tail end, but with an 8-day retention, shouldn't the backup window just roll on itself and space should no longer go up?

Our databases do not grow at 1% per day, yet storage seems to do.

Questions:

1. at which point would storage stop growing, given that retention is now only 8 days instead of 35?
2. Is there a way to completely drop the old (8+ - 35 days) bvackups, such that they no longer consume the storage? On the backup/restore page it only shows the last 8 backups (as expected), with no ability to see older ones.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out an inactive replication slot was responsble for space growth... It was not locking anything, just sitting there - and it was causing log space to grow exponentially each day.

Dropping replication slot (logical) was the solution to reclaiming space. Within 10-15 minutes, high watermark reset to normal.